# How to find if the number ends with 5?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
static int Sss()
{
    int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] numbers = new int[k];
    numbers = GenerateRandomNumbers(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < 10 || numbers[i] > 99)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
```

I need to do a method, Ssk(k), which generates k random numbers and returns the product of these numbers which are double digits and ends with 5.

Comment: Cast to a string and look at the last character

Comment: If you have numbers than number ending with 5 are (x mod 10) == 5.  Or in c# (x % 10) == 5.

Comment: @juharr : You answer is too complicated.  You just need to check if mod 10 equal 5

Comment: If you want to generate a random, two-digit number that ends in five then generate a random one-digit number between 1 and 9, multiply that by ten, and add five.

Comment: This is not clear. You need to be more specific in your question. The random numbers are double digits? But they can only end in 5? So we throw away the other random numbers? The product of k double-digit random numbers can easily exceed the int maximum. What happens then?

Answer (score 2):

A non-negative integer x ends in 5 when written as a decimal if and only if `x % 10 == 5` is true.

I note that you are returning an `int`, but ints can only go up to about two billion. The product of five two-digit numbers is almost certainly over that. You should use `long`, `decimal`, `double` or `BigInteger` instead, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

For any number you can check what the last digit is using by modulo operation, which in C# is a `%`, but works ONLY for integers. In your case you should check if `numbers[i]%10==5`.

Comment: Minor nit pick -- the `%` is the *remainder* operation in C# because it is defined as `x % y` is the same as `x - (x/y)*y`. That is, it is the *remainder* after the integer division operation.  That means that it can be negative; we do not normally think of the modulus as being negative.